# Can't open Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour

Tags: technical-issues, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

When I launch "Command & Conquer Generals Zero Hour" from icon on desktop, it doesn't open game, but instead opens "Rise of the reds" launcher. And when I open same app from installation folder it happens again. Does someone have same problem as me and know solution?

Answer (score 1):

Rise of the reds is a mod for command and conquer so you might have accidentally modded the game i would try reinstalling the game.

Comment: I have played both games normally since today, and today that started happening. But strange is that I haven't modified any files in game. It just happen spontaneously.

Comment: well try going to the settings in game

Comment: This literally CAN'T happen spontaneously, unless you installed the game from some unofficial source and they bundled it with this mod. Or someone else installed the mod on that PC.

Comment: your right. but what site did you buy the game from steam,origin,etc?

Comment: I would right-click the icon and see where the icon links to (directory) and track that down that way